# Angularjs: is it possible to bind events of different controllers dynamically at Runtime?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to build a platform, which allows users to combine the events of different components dynamically at runtime.

so i think for each component, it has Controller, Directive, and Service.

so i wonder is it possible to bind events of different controllers dynamically at Runtime?

e.g. i have now two components: Map and Weather,
if i click a poi at the map, then the weather updates. ( the user can also change other combinations of events at runtime ).

i did a little bit research on $broadcast, and $on. but it seems that can't be used as binding events at runtime.

Comment: I think the way to go is each of these components has to decide on what are the events that component want to publish(ie emit/broadcast) then other guys can subscribe to those events... You should not interfere with the workings of a component from outside

Comment: @ArunPJohny yeah, but which event to publish/subscribe is just not certain. depends on what the user wants. so a EventManager is need to control/register the events which should be fired.

Comment: If you look at the common design pattern used in plugin or component development(at least in jQuery domain) the component will always trigger those events irrespective of whether the user wants it or not(ie wants to have a subscriber)...